# Imputing Missing Values in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to impute a couple of columns in my data frame using Scikit-Learn `SimpleImputer`. I tried doing this, but with no luck. How should I modify my code? `a`, `b`, `e` are the columns in my data frame that I want to impute.

My data frame:

```py
    a   b   c   d      e
    NA  39  cat gray   20
    5   NA  dog brown  NA
    7   53  cat tan    33
    NA  NA  cat black  41
    4   24  dog tan    NA
```

My code:

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

miss_mean_imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)

miss_mean_imputer = miss_mean_imputer.fit(df["a", "b", "e"])

imputed_df = miss_mean_imputer.transform(df.values)

print(imputed_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `missing_values='NaN'` with `missing_values=np.nan` when instantiating the imputer and you should also make sure that the imputer is used to transform the same data to which it has been fitted, see the code below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

df = pd.DataFrame({
 'a': [np.nan, 5.0, 7.0, np.nan, 4.0],
 'b': [39.0, np.nan, 53.0, np.nan, 24.0],
 'c': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'],
 'd': ['gray', 'brown', 'tan', 'black', 'tan'],
 'e': [20.0, np.nan, 33.0, 41.0, np.nan]
})

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(df[['a', 'b', 'e']])

imputed_df = df.copy()
imputed_df[['a', 'b', 'e']] = imputer.transform(df[['a', 'b', 'e']])

print(imputed_df)
#           a          b    c      d          e
# 0  5.333333  39.000000  cat   gray  20.000000
# 1  5.000000  38.666667  dog  brown  31.333333
# 2  7.000000  53.000000  cat    tan  33.000000
# 3  5.333333  38.666667  cat  black  41.000000
# 4  4.000000  24.000000  dog    tan  31.333333
```